# How can I convert this to Java, perhaps using Maps

Tags: javascript, java, maps

I picked up a JS code for my assignment and I'm having problems achieving this in Java. My aim is to create predefined values of cities.

```
* Removed JS code *
```

How can I convert this to Java, perhaps using Maps, I have an idea. i just don't know how to put this together perfectly.

```
Map<String, Object> routes = new TreeMap<>();
routes.put("route1", "U");
routes.put("route2", "C");
routes.put("direction", Object);

Map<String, Map<String, Object>> cities = new HasHMap<>();
cities.put("NewYork", routes.get("route1"));
cities.put("LosAngeles", routes.get("route2"));
```

Comment: So you got the JS code and haven't started yet on the Java code. Seems like asking someone to do your homework. Better show your efforts and then ask question when stuck

Comment: It's a simple task. Just write a transpiler.

Comment: Could be done as an `enum` or a POJO, best to try something

Comment: @MadProgrammer enum would just store One Object type and not key Value as maps right?

Comment: Create valid POJO's as noted above, not kludges as you're trying to do. And do consider getting rid of the JS code part of the question as this isn't a translation service for borrowed code. All that is doing is generating down-votes, votes that could potentially block you from asking future questions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay

Comment: Note that POJO = plain old java object, a class that has fields and methods. Something less restrictive than a bean.

Comment: @leggo Nope, `enum` could store any number of predefined values, assuming you have a limited number you want to use (since the original JS was using `const`) (ps - I would have kept the JS in your question, along with your attempt, as it makes it more obvious what you are trying to achieve)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok, reading up on it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: ok if he keeps it, though he should remove all requests for converting it

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, it, then it probably becomes a better candidate for Stack Review

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels kindly check, I copied code from the answer & edited. please kindly check for improvements

Comment: @leggo: please see comments made in madprogrammer's answer

Comment: Question rolled back so as not to invalidate @MadProgrammer's answer

Comment: Thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels , i understand the confusion that it my cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your original concept...

```
const cities = {
  NewYork: {
    route1: 'U',
    route2: 'C',
    direction: (x, y)=>{
      return {x:x+2, y:y*2};
    },
  },
  LosAngeles: {
    route1: 'U',
    route2: 'C',
    direction: (x, y)=>{
      return {x:x+2, y:y*2};
    },
  },
};
```

I would either use a POJO (plain old Java object) or possibly an `enum` if you want to have a predefined set of values which can't be changed.

Starting with a `Direction` class to make this simpler...

```
public class Direction {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Direction(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

And possibly an `enum`

```
public enum City {
    NEW_YORK("U", "C"),
    LOS_ANGELES("U", "C");

    private String route1;
    private String route2;

    private Cities(String route1, String route2) {
        this.route1 = route1;
        this.route2 = route2;
    }

    public Direction direction(int x, int y) {
        return new Direction(x + 2, y * 2);
    }

}
```

Now, if you need to be able to create different cities at runtime, you might consider something more like...

```
public class City {

    private String route1;
    private String route2;

    private City(String route1, String route2) {
        this.route1 = route1;
        this.route2 = route2;
    }

    public String getRoute1() {
        return route1;
    }

    public String getRoute2() {
        return route2;
    }

    public Direction direction(int x, int y) {
        return new Direction(x + 2, y * 2);
    }

}
```

Remember, your in a OO language, make use of the constructs available to you to make your life simpler

Comment: I made some edits. It works for me, but Kindly check if it's good in terms of improvements. Thank you.

Comment: @leggo: your question has been answered by madprogrammer, and you should accept this answer. It's not fair game to now completely change your question by posting new shifting requirements. If I were you, I'd use what you learn from this answer and work out the rest of what you need to do. Tomorrow if stuck on something else, ask a new question, but please don't totally change the question, and by doing completely invalidate mad programmer's work.

Comment: No, i didn't change the Question, I just added the Previously deleted Code I was advised to remove. And I stated that I edited @MadProgrammer code to achieve everything I did. i just asked for Improvements from him.

Comment: @leggo: I'm thinking that he's posted improvements enough.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay thanks, i apologise for the confusion from my part. I'm kindof new here.